# How to put a search field extracting all data of particular entry in Unqork?

Tags: search, datatable, unqork

Also I am not able to collect data from fields and put them in Data table directly , also cannot generate a unique ID .

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt, noting input and expected output

Comment: Hi shubham , actually it is No Code development , so I just wanna know which component I should configure first and how . #NoCodingIncluded

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250272/search-functionality-in-unqork

Comment: Hey Nitigya! We have a private Stack Overflow team for the Unqork community so shoot me an email at colton@unqork.com and I'll give you access!