# Search functionality in Unqork

Tags: workflow, dashboard, unqork

I have a dashboard which has 10 records labeled as name, contact number and policy number. I need to have search bar. Using policy number I need to retrieve the record.

How can this be achieved using `Unqork`?

Comment: Hey Hemashree! We have a private Stack Overflow team for the Unqork community so shoot me an email at colton@unqork.com and I'll give you access!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you might be using the viewGrid to display the records under dashboard, there's a feature to enable filters in viewrid properties where it shows search bar kind of item for each column, based on the activity each column can be filtered accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to display your data in a `viewgrid`. `viewgrid`s have their own filter to allow filtering data.
2. Use `textfild to enter the policy number then use fiter to filter that data need to add dataworkflow for it.